# Could we use with and without extension on different actions in MonoRail?

Tags: c#, url, castle-monorail

I would like to build a web application on Castle MonoRail, I was wondering how can we use an action with extension and another action without extension? How can HTML helper generator url for us?

Ex:

- http://mysite.com/Products/list
- http://mysite.com/Products/abc.castle

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Yes**, you can, by using routing.
The exact method you need to use to get the routing working depends upon which version of Monorail you are using. However, adding routing can have some negative impact on performance unless you are careful.

It is also worth noting that you don't have to use the extension ".castle" or ".rails" in case this is what is distasteful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a routing role like

```
/<controller>/<action>.castle
```

and it would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for this.  Why would you want to access an action without using .rails or .castle?